# How to automate reports and send them to customers in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been looking for solution to automate the reports. I have many customers and many reports.
each customer has their own will to receive individual report on specific day to their given/subscribed email addresses. So I have customer and report name and weekday, weekly, monthly (different schedules) and list of customers where each report is sent to.

Is there any way to implement this automation using simple T-SQL?

I have been able to make report in Crystal report and through command like (use TSQL) to generate report output in any format, lets say, .pdf and based on customer list send them email on their scheduled day.

I do not want to do this all in Crystal Report, because there is already SSRS we have but my question is, Ids there any easy way that i pass a command line to my sql server report and that returns me output so that i can send email to my clients?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc872783.aspx

Comment: Use the SSRS subscriptions for the reports as @JesalynOlson pointed out

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you are just not using the Subscription for the report within the SSRS Report manager application?  This should allow you to automate any sending of the reports on a schedule.

Comment: Is Reporting service subscription API or any TSQL available? it ask for emails to send in TO.. CC etc, schedule. How do I do this automate programmatically or using TSQL? Hope you understand my question and provide solution if available. I have to provide some interface for customers where they setup report name and delivery schedule and list of emails who will be receiving these reports.

Comment: Is there any easy way that i pass a command line to my sql server report (report is already designed in SSRS) and that returns me output so that i can send email to my clients?

Comment: If you have a procedure that sends a db mail, you can create a table that you have the stored emails and create the script using that table, I would recommend you can probably just create a SQL Server job that runs that stored procedure.  You can have it run as often as you want pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stored procedure and execute it on a schedule. I have a proc I use (see below) its currently got the file link hard coded but you can use a lookup table of file locations and reference them with a slight modification to the proc.

```
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Sub NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @File NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @To NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CC NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DistName NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get Recipents
SELECT @To = COALESCE(@To + ';', '') + EmailAddress 
FROM tblDistribution_EmailAddress
WHERE (DistributionID = 1) AND (Active = 1) AND (Recipient = 'TO')


--Get CC'd Recipients
SELECT @CC = COALESCE(@CC + ';', '') + EmailAddress 
FROM tblDistribution_EmailAddress
WHERE (DistributionID = 1) AND (Active = 1) AND (Recipient = 'CC')


--Get Subject
SET @Sub = 'TEST EMAIL' + SUBSTRING(Convert(NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE()-1,101),4,2) +'.'+SUBSTRING(Convert(NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE()-1,101),1,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(Convert(NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE()-1,101),7,4)

--Set the body of Email
SET @body =   N'<style type="text/css">body {font-family: Tahoma;font-size:12px;} table{font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;table-layout: fixed} td{ border:1px solid black; padding:3px;} th{background-color:#F1F1F1;border:1px solid black; padding:3px;}</style>' +
'<Body><p>Dear All </p>' +
    '<p>Attached is the report needed.</p>' 
SET @body = @body + '</table><p>Regards</p><p>Your Server</p><p>IT</p></Body></html>'

--Attach File
SET @file = N'\\FileShar\NewShar\Customer_24042013.csv' (SELECT FilePath FROM dtLookUps..tblImportFiles WHERE(Active = 1) AND (Package = 1))

--Send Email
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients =               @To,
    @copy_recipients =      @CC,
    @body =                 @body,
    @body_format =          'HTML',
    @subject =              @Sub,
    @file_attachments = @File
```

Should hopefully get you started.

Comment: I know this. Thanks. My question is how do i automate subscription here? Is Reporting service subscription API or any TSQL available? it ask for emails to send in TO.. CC etc, schedule. How do I do this automate programmatically or using TSQL? Hope you understand my question and provide solution if available.

I have to provide some interface for customers where they setup report name and delivery schedule and list of emails who will be receiving these reports.

Comment: Report is already Designed in using SSRS, I want to send filter parameters, TO,CC then convert this report in PDF or Excel and send it any customer from Command Prompt

Comment: SQL Enterprise SSRS supports dynamic parameters in report subscriptions.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017